# How do i define some variables in logback.xml and be able to use that variable in my java code?

Tags: logback

So, I am making a custom appender and i want elasticsearch url and index pattern to be saved in logback.xml and somehow get that value in my java code and i also want to be able to override it if i want in my append() function. I am using maven for my project if that helps.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>

        </encoder>


    </appender>

    <appender name="myappender" class="esappender.EsAppender">
        <m_elasticSearchUrl>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx</m_elasticSearchUrl>
        <m_elasticSearchIndex>output-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</m_elasticSearchIndex>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>

        </encoder>

    </appender>

    <logger name="esappender" level="debug" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="myappender" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I thought directly metioning it in the tags will work and i could use it in my java code but it doesn't seem to work. When i search the internet i only find variables referenced in the logback itself but i want to be able to refrence it from append() function.

Comment: show your effort